# Update field from object Incident into object Base Element

Tags: apex, trigger

I built the apex, with help from here, to make a calculation between String (HH:MM) and Decimal (xxx.xx). All the calculation is working, but now I need to update the BMCServiceDesk__BMC_BaseElement__c object.

The variable **BH_Franquia__c** variable makes the select in the **BMCServiceDesk__BMC_BaseElement__c** table and the column that I need to update after performing all the calculation is **Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c**

I tried in several ways to set the value of the variable **Franquia_Restante_Calculada** to the column **Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c** of the variable **BH_Franquia__c**, but without success

```
trigger Trigger_CalculaBH_Estimativa on BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c (before update) {
    for(BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c BMC_inc: Trigger.new){
        try{
            String BMC_LayoutId = [SELECT Id 
                                   FROM BMCServiceDesk__ConsoleLayoutDetail__c 
                                   WHERE name = 'Requisição - Banco de Horas' limit 1][0].Id;
            If (BMC_inc.BMCServiceDesk__Status_ID__c == 'ABERTO' && BMC_inc.Estimativa_Banco_de_Horas__c <> NULL && BMC_inc.BMCServiceDesk__RF_FKLayout__c == BMC_LayoutId){
                //ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'ENTROU'));
                
                Decimal FranquiaContrato = [SELECT Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c
                      FROM BMCServiceDesk__BMC_BaseElement__c
                      WHERE Id =: BMC_inc.Contrato_de_Banco_de_Horas__c limit 1][0].Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c; //dominio decimal
                
                String Estimativa = BMC_inc.Estimativa_Banco_de_Horas__c; //dominio tempo
                
                List<String> Estimativa_Partes = Estimativa.split(':');
                Decimal Estimativa_Decimal = Decimal.valueOf(Estimativa_Partes[0]) + (Decimal.valueOf(Estimativa_Partes[1]) / 60.0);

                BMC_inc.Estimativa_de_uso_do_Banco_de_Horas__c = FranquiaContrato - Estimativa_Decimal;
                
                // Converter o resultado para dominio tempo
                Integer hours = BMC_inc.Estimativa_de_uso_do_Banco_de_Horas__c.intValue();
                Decimal minutes = (BMC_inc.Estimativa_de_uso_do_Banco_de_Horas__c - hours) * 60;
                String remainingTime = hours + ':' + minutes.round(System.RoundingMode.UP);
                
                String FranquiaRestante = remainingTime.replace(':', '.');
                Decimal Franquia_Restante_Calculada = Decimal.valueOf(FranquiaRestante);
                BMC_inc.Estimativa_de_uso_do_Banco_de_Horas__c = Franquia_Restante_Calculada;
                
                
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Trigger.new[0].addError(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it. To achieve it I wrote:

```
            List<BMCServiceDesk__BMC_BaseElement__c> recContratoUpdate = [SELECT Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c
                  FROM BMCServiceDesk__BMC_BaseElement__c
                  WHERE Id =: BMC_inc.Contrato_de_Banco_de_Horas__c limit 1];
            
            for (BMCServiceDesk__BMC_BaseElement__c rec : recContratoUpdate) {
                rec.Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c = Franquia_Restante_Calculada;
            }
            update recContratoUpdate;
```

This is the best way?